# To which large cardinal property this inaccessible cardinal is equal?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I want to define a "$t^\zeta$-unreachable" where $t^\zeta$ stands for a tuple of size $\zeta$. I'd call that tuple as the *index of reachability* of the cardinal in question.

I'll start with $0$-unreachability which actually  I take it here to mean accessibility. That is a cardinal $\kappa$ is $0$-unreachable if and only if it is empty or it is subnumerous to the power set of the union of a set $X$ of cardinals smaller than $\kappa$, where $|X| < \kappa$. (where *subnumerous* means *smaller than or equal* in cardinality).

Now by $1$-unreachable, I mean a cardinal $\kappa$ that is not $0$-unreachable and such that only the $0$-unreachables less than it are unbounded in it, it's obvious here that every $1$-unreachable cardinal is $\aleph_0$ or an inaccessible cardinal.

Similarly every $\alpha$-unreachable is not $\beta$-unreachable for all $\beta < \alpha$, and for each $\beta$ the set of all $\beta$-unreachables smaller than it is unbounded in it if and only if $\beta < \alpha$

Now we reach into a cardinal $\kappa$ that is $\kappa$-unreachable! Here this will be the point of change, this will be expressed by having a tuple with two entries in it, more precisely as: $[0,1]$-unreachable. (this would be a hyper-inaccessible cardinal).

We repeat the same process above, so an $[\alpha, \zeta]$-unreachable is not a $[\beta, \zeta]$-unreachable for all $\beta < \alpha$, and for each $\beta$ the set of all $[\beta, \zeta]$-unreachables smaller than it is unbounded in it if and only if $\beta < \alpha$

Now we reach into a cardinal $\kappa$ that is $[\kappa, \zeta]$-unreachable, now this would be expressed as $[0,\zeta+1]$, and so on...

We run the above process till we reach into a cardinal $\kappa$ that is $[0,\kappa]$-unreachable, now at that stage this would be expressed by a ternary tuple as: $[0,0,1]$-unreachable!

Now we continue running this process until we reach into a cardinal $\lambda$ that is $t^\lambda$-unreachable, the first one would be of the form "$[0,0,0,....,1(\text{ at } \lambda^{th} \text { entry })]$-unreachable".

The question is:

> What large cardinal property $\lambda$ is equal to?

From the Wikipedia page on **[inaccessible cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_cardinal#%CE%B1-unreachable_cardinals_and_hyper-unreachable_cardinals)**, I got the impression that a hyper-inaccessible is just an $[\alpha, 1]$-unreachable, while a hyper-hyper-inaccessible (i.e. a hyper$^2$-inaccessible) is an $[\alpha, 2]$-unreachable, and generally a hyper$^\delta$-inaccessible is just an $[\alpha, \delta]$-unreachable. So an $[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]$-unreachable can be a Mahlo. However, I might be wrong since I don't have that parcel of knowledge about large cardinal properties.

Note: I've changed the naming from *inaccessible* to unreachable in order to avoid confusion with a known terminology as advised in the comments.

Comment: Is your 1-inaccessible cardinal an inaccessible cardinal that is a union of accessible cardinals? But is every limit cardinal a union of accessible cardinals?

Comment: @HanulJeon, thanks for this note. I've corrected my formulation.

Comment: I suspect "[greatly Mahlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahlo_cardinal#%CE%B1-Mahlo,_hyper-Mahlo_and_greatly_Mahlo_cardinals)" might be the stopping point.

Comment: possibly even the more interesting question is to go beyond $\lambda$ by postulating it to be a set, and also postulating existing of an $t^\kappa$-unreachable for any set $\kappa$, and so iterating the process all along. I think this should pass greatly Mahlo's, not sure if it can reach reflecting cardinals?

Comment: In your 2nd paragraph I cannot understand "subnumerous to the power of the union of a set of cardinals". The union of a set of cardinals is a cardinal Y. What does the power of Y mean? And does subnunerous mean < or $\le$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the power of Y is the power set of Y that is the set of all subsets of Y, subnumerous mean cardinal $\leq$, I've edited the post to make this clear. Thanks

Comment: @bof, "$X$ is subnumerous to $Y$" means that "card $X$ $\leq$ card $Y$". I've added a note to clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: Why would a $(0,1)$-unreachable be a hyper-inaccessible cardinal, if a $\beta$-unreachable need not be $\alpha$-unreachable for $\alpha<\beta$? Because of this I'm not sure $\kappa$ being $\kappa$-unreachable corresponds to $\kappa$ being $\kappa$-inaccessible.